# Powershell Match Multiple Fields, including Encoded

Tags: xml, powershell, rss

Google has been my friend and I have made some progress on code that I am working on. But I am not a programmer by trade, so I got so far and now I am stuck.

I have an rss feed that I am trying to parse and search out for keywords. Once it finds one of the keywords, I would like for it to select the title, link and body of text. Ideally in an easy to read paragraph format.

```
$feed = [xml](New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/external.php?type=RSS2&forumids=746')
$results = $feed.rss.channel.Item | ? {$_.title  -match "boker"} | ft title, link, description -auto
@($results)
```

That is the code that I have gotten so far. Just as info the description field is not what I really want. I really want the encoded field, but it doesn't export correctly. It just says "encoded" when it is done.

The other thing that I want it to do. I want it to not only search title but also the encoded field for the same thing. If it finds the keyword in either place then it extracts the info.

This is how it will output today:

```
title                               link                                                                                                    description                    
-----                               ----                                                                                                    -----------                    
FS: CRKT Shrimp, Boker Microcom     http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/915409-FS-CRKT-Shrimp-Boker-Microcom?goto=newpost      1st Class shipping is includ...
SOLD: Boker Subcom and Subcom Titan http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/915337-SOLD-Boker-Subcom-and-Subcom-Titan?goto=newpost description
```

I would prefer for it to output:

```
title
link
encoded

title
link 
encoded
```

Let me know if you need anymore info. Once I have the formatting the way I want, I plan to run this as a scheduled task on a loop and have it email me anytime there are matches. And for it to keep a history so it doesn't send duplicates. But first things first, I want to get the basic output right first.

**EDIT**

Thank you both. I got it working, exactly what I asked. When I send the email to my phone, if I include the cdata/encoded field, it takes up too much room. The description field will probably work better on my phone. However it seems hit and miss. Sometimes the description field will be populated and sometimes it will be blank. Any ideas? It also does the same thing with the title field, sometimes it is blank.

Comment: Any ideas on the fields that show up blank occasionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the encoded property is wrapped in another property called the "#cdata-section", so you have to expand that as well.

To match on both properties just include both matches in your where condition separated by the `-or` operator. Your where condition would look like this:

```
?{ $_ -match "boker" -or $_.encoded."#cdata-section" -match "boker"}
```

Finally, to output as a list, use the format-list commandlet (alias fl), note how you have to expand the encoded property by provided a script block (enclosed in braces). So you end up with this:

```
$feed.rss.channel.Item | ?{ $_ -match "boker" -or $_.encoded."#cdata-section" -match "boker"} | fl title, link, {$_.encoded."#cdata-section"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Format-List instead of Format-Table e.g.:

```
$feed.rss.channel.Item | Where {$_.title  -match "boker"} | Format-List title, link, description
```

or

```
$feed.rss.channel.Item | ? {$_.title  -match "boker"} | fl title, link, description
```

Which outputs:

```
title       : FS: CRKT Shrimp, Boker Microcom
link        : http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/915409-FS-CRKT-Shrimp-Boker-Microcom?goto=newpost
description : 1st Class shipping is included, I take both PP personal and MO.

              1. CRKT Shrimp Silver: NIB. Good lockup, only thing that has been done is the little steel ring has been
              removed (but I still have it). $*11*

              2. Boker Microcom: Taken in and out of the sheath a few times, used a few times as...

title       : SOLD: Boker Subcom and Subcom Titan
link        : http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/915337-SOLD-Boker-Subcom-and-Subcom-Titan?goto=newpost
description : description
```